# Write about academic plans

Tags: academic-writing

A graduate school application form asks me to write about my academic plans.

What I can think of is only the course arrangement in graduate study.

So am I missing something ?

Comment: I have opened a [meta question](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/397/should-we-be-answering-questions-about-what-to-write-about) about this question and whether or not questions like it should be on-topic.

Comment: [Choosing research ideas to include in a statement of purpose](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/1529/14341) in Academia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are asking you about what are you planning to work on graduate study,especially your thesis.

```
What I can think of is only the course arrangement in graduate study.
```

If you know your course arrangement, you should know your interests in that school. If you have a specific thesis in your mind you can write about it. Otherwise list your interests and say you would like to work on them. Control that your interests matches with their offerings. What they are doing is actually helping you to understand if you and that school is a match.

Lets say you are interested in image processing and pattern recognition. List which courses you would like to take for this purpose. List labs, projects and professors you may work with.

Do your homework about school.

Comment: Wow, thanks, I think my eyes are opened! But what if I applied for a MS program, which maybe course oriented. Are there many chances to work with professors? This is just a digress, but I wonder about it.